# How do I use the ActionListener (this) command in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a simple Tic-Tac-Toe program which uses both the terminal and a before game UI. I'm quite a noob at this, so please go easy. When I try to use ActionListener on a method I called, I get this error : `Non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.`

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Random ;
import java.util.Scanner ;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane ;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;
import javax.swing.JPanel ;
import java.util.InputMismatchException ;
import java.awt.BorderLayout ;
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import javax.swing.JTextArea ;
import javax.swing.JButton ;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton ;

class TicTacToe
 {
    public int inp1 ; 
    public int inp2 ;

    public static void main(String []args) 
    {
        popupintroscreen();

    }
    public static void popupintroscreen()
    {

        JTextArea introtext = new JTextArea("Hello and welcome to TicTacToe v.1.0");
        introtext.setEditable(false);
        introtext.setLineWrap(true);
        introtext.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JButton startgamebutton = new JButton("Start Game");
        JButton.addActionListener(this);



        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(introtext);
        content.add(startgamebutton);

        JFrame introscreen = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        introscreen.setSize(400,400);
        introscreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        introscreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        introscreen.add(content);
        introscreen.setVisible(true);




    }
}`
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `this` refers to the current object context, but you're in a `static` method which by definition doesn't have an object context, so `this` doesn't exist. The object that `this` refers to (if you resolve the `static` problem first) also needs to implement the `ActionListener` interface and any required methods before it can be used in the way you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you JonK, but can you explain that in simpler terms please? I'm a real newbie :(

Comment: Do you understand what the `static` keyword means? It can be quite a difficult thing to get your head around if you're new to Object-Oriented languages.

Comment: Well, till now I know that the static keyword states that the object belongs to the class and not to any instance of it, but if you could explain more, I'd be very grateful. Not only am I new to Object oriented languages, but I'm new to programming languages as well.

Comment: You're sort of there by the sounds of it. Think of `this` as just another variable - it just happens to reference the current "object context". If you're inside a non-`static` method, the "object context" is the object that you called the method on. For instance: `introtext.setEditable(false);` - inside the `setEditable()` call, `introtext` is the object context. As you've said though, `static` things are **class level**, so to call `popupintroscreen()` you (implicitly) called `TicTacToe.popupintroscreen()`. That means you have no object context, because `TicTacToe` isn't an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question then here when you define your class

```
class TicTacToe
```

You also need to specify that `TicTacToe` implements the [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface (and to implement the one method it has);

```
class TicTacToe implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("TicTacToe.actionPerformed: " + e);
  }
  public static void main(String []args) 
  {
    new TicTacToe().popupintroscreen();
  }
  public void popupintroscreen() { // <-- not static.
    // ...
  }
}
```

Additionally, to use `this` in `popupintroscreen` it cannot be a static method. Finally, you need an instance of `TicTacToe`.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you did there. Should I add this to my code, and is the SOP necessary? I would also like to know what the function of @Override is. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I added a little more explanation. Replace the SOP with what you want to happen on the Action. The Override ensures that you are actually implementing a *super* method. If you get the signature wrong and don't implement the correct method that's what's known as a bad thing.

Comment: It's probably not a problem in this case, but just be aware that having the `@Override` annotation on a method specified by an interface is a compile-time error prior to Java 1.6.

Comment: Positive - it bit me a few days ago!

Comment: Now it's just weird. Compiling against the same version on different machines (both 32-bit) produces different results. Mine compiles fine, the other does not. JAVA_HOME is set to the same JDK version on both. Not going to expend any more effort looking into it though, most people hopefully aren't using versions that old anymore anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the way the code is written is inherently wrong.

You are not defining any ActionListener here. Just calling addActionListener(this) will not serve any purpose. You need the implementation of ActionListener. Replace the line 
`JButton.addActionListener(this); 
// you have to use the object of JButton - i.e. startgamebutton, not the JButton class here! addActionListener is not a static method of JButton`

with this (using anonymous inner class):

```
startgamebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("In actionPerformed");
    // other code to handle the event when the button is clicked
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction on JButton, just a little absent mindedness on my part.Thanks for the code man, really cleared it up. I don't have to use e after ActionEvent, right? 'Cause i like explanatory, albeit lengthy, variable names. I'm still learning.

Comment: Yeah 'e' is just a param name. You can name it anything as per Java variable naming rules. cheers!